# Unable to consume MSBuild properties in service resolving source generator

Tags: c#, .net, sourcegenerators, csharp-source-generator

I use [Injectio](https://github.com/loresoft/Injectio) and I'm having issue resolving the MSBuild properties. These are also documented in the [source generator cookbook](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/main/docs/features/source-generators.cookbook.md#consume-msbuild-properties-and-metadata).

I made a simple Console application as a minimal reproducible example and initially added Injectio as a NuGet package which I then replaced with local Injectio project reference, so that it helps me debug the MSBuild properties and see what's wrong, more specifically [this line of code](https://github.com/loresoft/Injectio/blob/main/src/Injectio.Generators/ServiceGenerator.cs#L68):

```cs
    public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        if (!Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Debugger.Launch();
        }

        ...
```

It ignores the property group below in my `.csproj` file. Why? Do I have to do CompilerVisibleProperty or something? This was also documented in the [Injectio README](https://github.com/loresoft/Injectio), scroll down to the bottom.

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <InjectioName>Library</InjectioName>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

All this property is supposed to do is let me use custom name for the registrator instead of `services.AddTest()`, e.g. in this case it should be `services.AddLibrary()`.

```cs
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddTest(); // Expected: => services.AddLibrary()
    })
```

### Test.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <InjectioName>Library</InjectioName>
    </PropertyGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Injectio" Version="1.0.33" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="7.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
</Project>
```

### Program.cs

```cs
using Injectio.Attributes;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddTest();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(x => x.AddConsole())
    .UseConsoleLifetime()
    .Build();

await host.RunAsync();

[RegisterSingleton(ServiceType = typeof(IHostedService))]
internal sealed class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly PeriodicTimer _timer = new(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (await _timer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Worker running at: {Time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Oh, no! Something bad happened");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I had to add `CompilerVisibleProperty` to the `.csproj` file, so it recognizes the MSBuild property.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
        <EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>true</EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <InjectioName>Library</InjectioName>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <CompilerVisibleProperty Include="InjectioName" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Injectio" Version="1.0.33" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="7.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
</Project>
```